# Change interface language of Chrome to English

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, language

The interface language of my Windows 10 is English. Also of the browsers, except Chrome, which is in Hebrew that I cannot read. I want to change the interface language on Chrome to English too. What I've seen in the web is advice on how to do that, but they all tell you how to do that if your interface is already English. Whatever I do after clicking on the settings icon of Chrome, I get bla=bla where all (Hebrew) letters are replace by little rectangles. Is there a way to get what want without getting nonsense on the screen?

Comment: The quickest solution is probably to uninstall Chrome and then install an English language version ...

Answer (score 4):

Okay, try this. I've posted a lot of pictures so you can do it as blindly as possible:

1. Write `chrome://settings` in your address bar.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page. You'll need to show the advanced options, by clicking **the blue link at the end**.
3. Scroll a little bit more, until you find the language section, and click the button in the orange square:

[image: Language settings section]

4. Once there, add a new language:

[image: Adding a new language]

5. Choose the language you want (*I had to choose a variant, like "United States English", instead of just "English", for this to work*):

[image: Choosing the new language]

6. Accept to add the new language:

[image: Accepting the new language]

7. Set the new language as the default for Chrome's interface:

[image: Setting the new lang as default for Chrome's interface]

8. Finally, **restart Chrome**.